# When I try to copy a button, it will not copy it's properties

Tags: visual-studio-2015, copy-paste, windows-forms-designer

I'm making a project that contains simular buttons. When I try to copy a button, it doesn't copy the properties to the new button. I have never had this problem before. And the problem only occurs when I try to copy a button with those settings (I tried to make an exact copy of it by hand and copy it , but that did not matter), not with other buttons.

Comment: wpf ? windows forms ?

Comment: It's in Windows forms.

Comment: you can copy the button from the `xxx.designer.cs` File. All values for all properties are set in there.

Comment: That would take too much time, I need to make 50 copies.